# SP2013 , Control Templates ctx.ListData.ResultTables Not available in IE 11

Tags: 2013, search-results, display-template

I am trying to fetch the total count of result items in my content search webpart's Control template using the code:

```
 ctx.ListData.ResultTables[0].ResultRows.length
```

Now this line works perfectly in Chrome but in IE 11 , `ctx.ListData` object does not have `ResultTables` property and it fails. Any idea if i am missing anything or any work around?